# Extract part of url with dynamic form

Tags: python-3.x

I need to extract part of strings that represent urls.Its from an api response and I need to get specific part(its called ASIN)

Examples

- [https://www.amazon.com/Hayvenhurst-Minimalist-Blocking-Wallets-Obsidian/dp/B091JJZPCM/ref=sr_1_58?keywords=mens+wallet&qid=1651036806&sr=8-58](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B091JJZPCM)
- [https://www.amazon.com/Champion-Mens-Advocate-Bifold-Wallet/dp/B07P3CTC3Z/ref=sr_1_56?keywords=mens+wallet&qid=1651036806&sr=8-56](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P3CTC3Z)
- [https://www.amazon.com/Timberland-Hunter-Leather-Passcase-Trifold/dp/B00MCW7OGM/ref=sr_1_55?keywords=mens+wallet&qid=1651036806&sr=8-55](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MCW7OGM)

For me to extract the ASIN number, its after the `/dp` and before `/ref` part of the url string

```
 print(f"asin {url.split('/')[-2]}")
```

prints `B091JJZPCM,B07P3CTC3Z`

But often times, some urls has different pattern, like

- https://www.amazon.com/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_btf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A10365631KNJTYYLZ8RME&qualifier=1651036806&id=2996869036517091&widgetName=sp_btf&url=%2FWustentre-Minimalist-Leather-Blocking-Tracker%2Fdp%2FB09NHTNTH8%2Fref%3Dsr_1_59_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dmens%2Bwallet%26qid%3D1651036806%26sr%3D8-59-spons%26psc%3D1

In this case, how do you extract the ASIN part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by

```
        url = "https://amazon.com/**********************"
        asin = url.split("/")[-2]
        if "html" in asin:
            print(f"url {asin}")
            parsed_url = urlparse(url)
            captured_value = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)["url"][0]
            url = f"https://amazon.com{captured_value}"
            print(f"captured url {url}")
            asin = url.split("/")[-2]
            print(f"captured asin {asin}")
```